# Can I use NServiceBus 2.5 on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, nservicebus

Can I use NServiceBus 2.5 on Windows Azure? Or do I need to wait for NServiceBus 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the work is being done on the 3.0 branch in [GitHub](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus).  If you feel more confident about the 2.5 branch, you'll have to port the 3.0 work back to the 2.5 way of doing things which is a bit different.